# Como fazer SELECT em mais de uma tabela do banco?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Tenho duas tabelas no banco: cep e usuarios.
Posso fazer uma única consulta para pegar campos das duas tabelas? Ambas tem o idCep.
Quero pegar os dados de endereço da tabela cep e o nome e usuário da tabela usuarios.

Como estou trabalhando com php, estou usando PDO com o banco de dados.

Segue print das tabelas:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Esse seria o básico:

```
SELECT *
  FROM USUARIOS
  JOIN CEP ON CEP.IDCEP = USUARIOS.IDCEP
```

Se quiser limitar as colunas:

```
SELECT USUARIOS.*, CEP.cep, CEP.uf, CEP.cidade, CEP.bairro, CEP.logradouro
  FROM USUARIOS 
  JOIN CEP ON CEP.IDCEP = USUARIOS.IDCEP
```

Consideração:

O número do CEP (coluna cep) já é a chave da tabela. Então você não deve ter um IdCep, primeiro por não fazer sentido, segundo por perder normalidade.

Comment: Por perder normalidade?

Comment: Esqueci de mencionar, mas estou usando PDO.
$dadosUsuario=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios JOIN cep ON WHERE cep.idCep=:usuarios.idCep");

Comment: Sim, @GustavoSevero, vc passa a ter duas chaves, tornando possível ter CEPs repetidos na tabela. Veja aqui sobre [Normalização de Dados](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normaliza%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_dados).

Comment: @GustavoSevero: Arruma esse `ON WHERE`, segue: `$dadosUsuario=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios JOIN cep ON cep.idCep=:usuarios.idCep");`

Comment: OK, deu certo.
Só o seguinte, apareceu mais de um resultado para essa consulta. Não posso dizer que ambos tem que ser iguais ao tal id? Pois TODOS os idCep da tabela cep tem o mesmo idCep para a tabela usuarios, então vão aparecer inúmeros resultados.

Comment: @GustavoSevero ERRATA: `$dadosUsuario=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios JOIN cep ON cep.idCep = usuarios.idCep AND cep.idCep=:usuarios.idCep");`

Comment: Não mudou nada no resultados kkk
Aparecem vários.
Quero fazer algo do tipo:
SELECT * FROM usuarios JOIN cep ON cep.idCep = usuarios.idCep WHERE idCep=:idCEP

Answer (score 3):

```
Select CEP.logradouro,
       CEP.bairro,
       CEP.cidade,
       CEP.uf,
       Usuarios.nome,
       Usuarios.usuario
  From CEP
  Inner Joint Usuarios
    on CEP.idCep = Usuarios.idCep
```

Comment: Acho que isso pode ajudar

Answer (score 0):

Basta fazer `join` entre as duas tabelas

```
select *
    from Usuario, Cep
    where Usuario.idCep = Cep.idCep
```